# Helm init fails

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Running helm init fails

I tried executing on MacOS Mojave 10.14.5:

`helm init`

```
$HELM_HOME has been configured at /Users/johnnydepp/.helm.
Error: error installing: Post https://192.168.99.103:8443/apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/kube-system/deployments: Gateway Timeout
```

Expected output is it should install Tiller to my running Kubernetes cluster. It will also set up any necessary local configuration.

Comment: Are you able to perform kubectl commands on the Kubernetes cluster you're trying to install Helm on?

Comment: No, executing kubectl commands shows: `Unable to connect to the server: Gateway Timeout`

Comment: Then that's your problem :) You need to make sure you can access your Kubernetes cluster in order for Helm to operate on it.

Comment: Ok, solved the answer is: we have to insert IP address (192.168.99.103) inside `no_proxy` bash script

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
kubectl -n kube-system create serviceaccount tiller 

kubectl create clusterrolebinding tiller \
  --clusterrole cluster-admin \
  --serviceaccount=kube-system:tiller 

helm init --service-account tiller --history-max 200
```

Share output from the below command:

```
kubectl get cs
```

```
NAME                 STATUS    MESSAGE             ERROR
controller-manager   Healthy   ok                  
scheduler            Healthy   ok                  
etcd-0               Healthy   {"health":"true"}
```

Comment: Running first command shows: "Unable to connect to the server: Gateway Timeout"

Comment: can you connect kubernetes cluster?

Comment: I am facing the same issue with kub version 1.16 & helm 2.16. ```kubectl version``` returns the version of client & server without error. Also, kubectl apply -f <to-any-other-deployment> also just works fine after trying the commands mentioned here.  Any suggestions?